# How to stopupdatingLocation when the app goes to background (ios6)

Tags: ios

I have instantiated locationManager in many of my view controllers. In order to save on battery, I want to stop the locationmanager from updating the location, so I was thinking of calling stopUpdatingLocation inside viewDidUnload in my VCs but viewDidUnload is being deprecated in ios6. Is there a clean way for me to stop all the updatinglocation?

Thanks!
Cuong

Answer (score 1):

You can use the UIApplicationDelegate method :

```
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
```

Inside this method you can call stopUpdatingLocation.

Answer (score 1):

stop Updating the location in

```
   - (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
   {
    //stop updating Location

      }
```

Answer (score 0):

An earlier answer suggested calling `stopUpdatingLocation` from `applicationWillResignActive`.  The better solution is to make the call from `applicationDidEnterBackground` instead.

I've found that calling `stopUpdatingLocation` from `applicationWillResignActive` causes the alert that asks the user for permission to use the location to disappear immediately before the user can tap anything.

This occurs because `applicationWillResignActive` is called when the permission dialog appears. This will call `stopUpdatingLocation` immediately after `startUpdatingLocation`, causing the dialog to immediately disappear.